# Get value from Firebase Database Object

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm simply trying to get a username value from my firebase database and display it in a console log statement but I am having trouble doing this. This is what I have so far.

Right now all it is doing is getting the object and not the actual child value. How do I get the child value so then it can be displayed.

[image]

**getUsername.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseObjectObservable, FirebaseListObservable  } from 'angularfire2/database';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile-setup',
  templateUrl: 'profile-setup.html',
})
export class ProfileSetupPage {
  profileData: FirebaseObjectObservable<Profile>

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {

  showUsername($event) {
    let data = this.profileData = this.afDatabase.object(`profile/`)
    console.log(data.username);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You will need to somehow use the ID of the object to locate the username.  This is unavoidable.  You can either add it to the query, or use it when reaching into the object.

Comment: okay so if I add profile/WhateverIDIs how would I get the actual username value?

Comment: Perform the query and log its results.  It should be evident how to find the fields you're looking for.  I don't work with Angular at all so I don't know the specifics.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subscribe to the data first and put it in a object to use the data.

Answer (score 0):

Define model(interface) named `user(username, age)` and import in `getUsername.ts`. And also you need to pass the unique `userid` as the argument.

```
showUsername($event) {
    let data = this.afDatabase.object(`profile/`+<string>userid);
    data.valuechanges().subscribe( user => console.log(user.username));
  }
```